# Collection column exists, but somehow doesn't at the same time

Tags: php, laravel, collections

i am at this error for some hours now, and i cant resolve it by myself.

this is the code:

$repeated_entry = Product_Market::where('produto_id', '=', $product->id)
->where('market_id', '=', $market->id)->get();

```
            $repeated_entry_update = Product_Market::where('produto_id', '=', $product->id)
            ->where('market_id', '=', $market->id);


            if($repeated_entry->count())
            {
            
                $repeated_entry_update->update(['amount_requested' => $repeated_entry->amount_requested + $request->product_amount,
                    'amount_left' => $repeated_entry->amount_requested + $request->product_amount,
                    
                ]);
            }
            else
            {
                    
                    product_market::create(['produto_id' => $product['id'],
                    'market_id' => $market['id'], //saves the info ghatered to the product_market relationship
                    'amount_requested' => $request->product_amount, //table
                    'amount_left' => $request->product_amount,
                    'amount_sold' => '0'
                    
                ]);
            }
```

the error says Property [amount_requested] does not exist on this collection instance. but it does exist

if i put a "DD($repeated_entry);" before the first if, to see the collection i get this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O63S7.png)

i can see the "amount_requested" RIGHT THERE, it is indeed in the collection, it might be completly obvious, and i just need some sleep, but i thought of asking for some help, (and dont mind the quality of the code, i am a noobie trying to learn)

ive tried other ways to get to the value in the collection, but it needs to stay a collection to work with the rest of the code, and i am expecting to sleep and maybe i undestand something in the morning that i cant see rn, sorry for the dumb question

Comment: Collections do not have a property named `amount_requested` ... an object contained in the Collection might though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$repeated_entry_update = Product_Market::where('produto_id', '=', $product->id)
        ->where('market_id', '=', $market->id);
```

to

```
$repeated_entry_update = Product_Market::where([
    'produto_id' => $product->id,
    'market_id' => $market->id
])->first();
```

You need to add `->first()` to actually get the object, cleared up the where condition a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`$repeated_entry` is a Collection instance. I assume you need the first entry. You need to use `first` after `get`.

```
$repeated_entry = Product_Market::where('produto_id', '=', $product->id)
    ->where('market_id', '=', $market->id)
    ->get();

$first_entry = $repeated_entry->first();
```

Then, change the condition if there's a matching entry:

```
if ($first_entry) {
```